# How can I create active hyperlinks for cross references in Texinfo DVI/PDF?

Tags: documentation, tex-core, texinfo, dvi

The [Texinfo PDF manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.pdf) has cross references as hyperlinks through the document.

When I create a PDF from my own Texinfo source files, the DVI file does not contain active links, though the cross references are otherwise fine.

I can't find this documented in the Texinfo manual, nor see it implemented as a recent feature in the [news](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/trunk/NEWS?root=texinfo).

How can I create cross references as hyperlinks through the document?

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided on the texinfo mailing list:

If you use `pdftex` to generate a PDF rather than go through `tex` to create a DVI file, you get the hyperlinks.